# Dynamic LINQ2Entities query cannot convert IEnumerable to bool

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

The establishment and organisation lines here give the error that they cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable to bool. What am I missing? I can't use greedy operators until the end of the method. I'm sure it's something simple, yet I can't see it.

```
IQueryable<User> query = context.Users;

if (usvm.EstablishmentId > 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserEstablishments
        .Where(y => y.UserEstablishmentId == usvm.EstablishmentId));

if (usvm.OrganisationId > 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserEstablishments
        .Where(y => y.Establishment.OrganisationId == usvm.OrganisationId));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(usvm.Forename))
    query = query.Where(x => x.Forename == usvm.Forename);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(usvm.Surname))
    query = query.Where(x => x.Surname == usvm.Surname);

if (usvm.DOB != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.DOB == usvm.DOB);

List<User> m = query.ToList();
return ToViewModel(m);
```

Comment: Where do you set the usvm ?

Comment: It's a view model passed from a controller. The values are there so that's not the issue. It's getting the query right I can't seem to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method:

```
if (usvm.EstablishmentId > 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserEstablishments
        .Any(y => y.UserEstablishmentId == usvm.EstablishmentId));

if (usvm.OrganisationId > 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserEstablishments
        .Any(y => y.Establishment.OrganisationId == usvm.OrganisationId));
```

Comment: both Establisment and Organisation should use any